# Военный или Армейский. Когда употреблять?

Tags: выбор-слов, синонимы

Есть разница между синонимами "Армейский" и "Военный"? И когда лучше написать "армейский", а когда "военный"?

1. **Армейский** грузовик. / **Военный** грузовик.
2. **Армейские** склады. / **Военные** склады.
3. **Армейская** одежда. / **Военная** одежда.
4. **Армейская** база. / **Военная** база.
5. **Армейский** городок. (местн.) / **Военный** городок. (местн.)

Comment: Не всегда, не всегда... *Нам ведь давали в пайке табак, снятый по срокам хранения с **армейских складов**, — авантюра гигантских масштабов: на лагерь списывались все продукты, что вылежали сроки хранения* (В. Т. Шаламов. Колымские рассказы (1954-1961)).

Comment: Если у вас есть конкретная фраза-другая, где встречаются эти слова, давайте её обсудим. Только так вы сможете получить внятный ответ. А сопоставить значения отдельных слов вы сможете по словарям.

Comment: Вообщем "военный" - это общее название для всего - для армии, флота и вообще чего угодно связанного с войной) А армейский - относится только к сухопутной армии. ТАкже военный - это русское слово, и "военный" - скорее всего речь идет о наших войсках, а армейский - это интернациональный термин и речь может идти о любой сухопутной армии. военный>армейский.